# What's the Best Placement for Save/Cancel Buttons on Very Long Forms?

Tags: buttons, placement, forms, save

I have a big project creation form having atleast having 30-40 fields where i have already grouped the relevant fields as a set(splitting into 3 columns) with proper headers, but still i have a long form.

My Question is where should i place the Save/Cancel/Edit buttons..? I am showing Edit only in read only mode. I have placed bottom left hand corner as user fills the form from top to bottom and hit save. Sometimes, they might not fill all the fields just fill the top section want to save the form, so in that case the user needs to scroll all the way to bottom.

Is there any data or research supporting this pattern? Is there another approach you recommend? I'm not as interested in official guidelines, as much as research-backed principles and the corresponding sources.

Comment: put them both on the top right corner *and* the bottom right corner

Comment: I think that's not a good idea to place buttons both at top and bottom

Comment: Just as data: Opera has save and reset buttons at the end of every section and all sections folded away by default; Sharepoint has one set at the top and one at the bottom. Opera's approach is ambiguous in that it's not clear whether it only saves changes in that section.

Comment: Finally, i agree to show the toolbar always at a fixed position and let only the form  scroll.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another option, is to scroll the form inside a container, and leave one set of buttons.

Rather than having the entire page scroll and the buttons not always being visible on the screen?

Comment: if you meant 'making button panel visible at all times, but on the bottom of the form, while enabling scrolling for the rest of the form (similar to facebook's or twitter's top panel, but... on the bottom)' - than that's what i'd answer.

Comment: @exp, ya, basically like that

Comment: Even new gmail UI has handled similarly, if you compare with old UI..thanks chad, exp

Answer (score 4):

I like the approach taken by [Jetbrains Teamcity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) (a continuous integration tool).

The form has regular save/cancel buttons at the end - for the case where the user fills out all the fields from top to bottom.

In addition, as soon as a change has been made, an "overlay" appears at the bottom of the screen with a message advising that there are unsaved changes - and with a "Save" button right there.

It doesn't matter where the users scrolls, there's a save button right there in the centre of the bottom edge of the window.

Answer (score 1):

Having two button group at the bottom and top makes sense in your case.

If it's possible put content in three tabs in this way user should complete each step that he wants, and then one button group would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the user already fill very long forum Its correct place to put at the bottom center i think, because its easy to access. If its top right corner means again they need scroll and then choose its very difficult to access.

Comment: How about both the top and the bottom of the form?